# wordpress different banner images for each pages - dynamically

Tags: php, wordpress

My website consist of 5 inner pages, and I want to use different banner images for each page. The page is with side bar, but I want a full width banner, so I used a code which I got from wordpress and its working

this is the code..

```
    <div class="banner">
<?php
if( is_page('About') ) $img = 'bannerAbout.jpg';
elseif( is_page('Services') ) $img = 'bannerServices.jpg';
elseif( is_page('Testimonials') ) $img = 'bannerTestimonials.jpg';
elseif( is_page('Testimonials') ) $img = 'bannerTestimonials.jpg';
elseif( is_home() ) $img = 'bannerBlog.jpg';
else $img = 'banner.jpg';?>
<img alt="" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/<?php echo $img;?>" />
</div>
```

My question is, How Can I call 'Featured Image' of each page in this code? between $img=""

Or any plug-for this?

If I can call the featured image, then its easy to upload images, otherwise I need to use FTP all the time to change.
Please help me.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code to your theme's functions.php

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post', 'page' ) );
```

this will enable featured image for post and page

Then in your page.php file add this code
before content and sidebar

```
<?php 
global $post;
echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'full'); // visit http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail for more info
?>
```

Comment: thanks, already featured image is enabled in pages. I can add featured image, but I don't know how to show this? Because I am using a page with side bar (Yes I need side bar widgets in all page),  I can't show full width images as banner, so I used this code. Can I call this 'featured image' in each $img=" FeaturedImage.jpg " ? And I am Designer, new to wordpress & PHP, please consider this too :)

Comment: well in that case you need to edit your page.php to make the image full width, you should put the image out side of sidebar and content if am not mistaken

Comment: Yes its working, I removed the above code and added your code before sidebar. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Place below code in each condition

```
global $post
echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID,'full' );
```

`full` will take the full size of image what ever you have uploaded